# I have created the radio buttons using jquery, now I want style them using css

Tags: jquery, css

i have created the radio buttons using jQuery as follows

```
function load_genders(target){
    genders = new Array("Male", "Female");
    output = "";
    i=0;
    for(i in genders){
        output += "<input type='radio' name='gender' id='"+genders[i]+"' value='"+genders[i]+"'>"+genders[i];
    }
    $(target).before(output);
}
load_genders("#genders_errors");
```

now I want style them using css but unable to do so. kindly guide me how to style these.
Thank you

Comment: what style? with jquery or plain css? show us your tried style.

Answer (score 0):

put your class name when you are going to generate them

```
 for(i in genders){
        output += "<input type='radio' name='gender' class='rdo_class' id='"+genders[i]+"' value='"+genders[i]+"'>"+genders[i];
    }
```

and put your style logic(rdo_class) in your website css file.

Hope it helps you

Comment: unfortunately this is not working please advise something else thankyou

Comment: which style you want to apply on radio button ?
can you please clarify more ?

Comment: actually brother I want to change the appearance of radio buttons their color, their style also want to add some background color to these.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your element as in below and specify styles in css.

```
output += "<input type='radio' class = 'gender' name='gender' id='"+genders[i]+"' value='"+genders[i]+"'>"+genders[i];
```

Comment: we can also style them without adding class. But we don't know what OP is trying to do.